# GA measure product bundles

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

On a webshop we are showing product bundles. This is a combination of two singular products, but both as a bundle, you get 5% discount.

The bundle is shown on a product page, and it shows a bundle of the product from the product page plus a related product.

To measure impressions and clicks, I think I need to use `ec:addPromo` ([see GA guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#measuring-promos)).

But how will I measure the checkout and eventually the transaction? 
When I add a bundle to the cart, do I add a `addPromo` or do I need to `addProduct` for the two products in the bundle? Some for the transaction, we want to measure the individual product sales, but we also want to know how the bundles perform.

Answer (score 0):

You just need an `addProduct` for two product from your bundle. Enhanced E-commerce is not that helpful with measuring the promo activities. The reports will only show you if a transaction is associated with promo impressions and clicks.
Take care to send promo click and product actions with separate events